# implementing custom java class in jruby

Tags: java, jruby

I am trying to implement a collection of java classes from the [Stanford NLP Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) in jRuby

I am able to implement regular Java in jRuby, but not the Stanford Parser classes

```
#my requires/imports/includes, included multiple versions to be safe
require 'java'
include Java
require 'c:\\stanford-parser\\stanfordparser.jar'
require 'C:\\Stanford-Parser\\Current\\stanford-parser.jar'
require 'c:\\sun\\stanfordparser'
require 'rubygems'
include_class 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser'


#try to create an object of the java class i am importing, LexicalizedParser
lp = edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
#the line above is what causes the error

#check if regular Java is working
list = java.util.ArrayList.new 
a = "1"
b = "2"
list.add(a)
list.add(b)
d = list[0]
puts d # all of this works
```

I get this error

```
~\rubyjavatest\lib\main.rb:15: undefined local variable or method `edu' for main:Object (NameError)
```

(the ~ represents I cut out the whole path to shorten this)

also if I try this:

```
lp = java::edu::stanford::nlp.parser::lexparser::LexicalizedParser
```

I get this error

```
~\rubyjavatest\lib\main.rb:15: cannot load Java class java.edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser (NameError)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: i am assuming you got this to work.  i am getting a Loading parser from serialized file /u/nlp/data/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ...  File not found: /u/nlp/data/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `lp = LexicalizedParser.new`

You need to call `new` like you did with ArrrayList.  Also, you shouldn't need to list the fully qualified class name after you call `include_class`.

I am not familiar with the Stanford NLP Parser, so I am assuming this will work.  It might be necessary to pass additional parameters to the constructor.