# getting started with Stanford Parser in jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, stanford-nlp

I'm looking to add some text parsing in my rails app, and have been going in circles for the past few days looking for any tutorials or hints as to how to get this working.

I am completely new to Java, but nothing like jumping in with both feet.

i suspect the following code doesn't belong in my controller, and should likely be in a model, but I'm just seeing if I've got all the pieces in the right place at this point.

I borrowed this code from this SO question, [implementing custom java class in jruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161312/implementing-custom-java-class-in-jruby), because I was having trouble finding any sort of example code.

```
#my requires/imports/includes, included multiple versions to be safe
require 'java'
#include Java
require '/media/sf_Ruby192/java_progs/parser/stanford-parser.jar'
#require '/media/sf_Ruby192/java_progs/parser/'
require 'rubygems'
include_class 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser'

class ParseController < ApplicationController

    def index
lp = LexicalizedParser.new
    #check if regular Java is working
list = java.util.ArrayList.new 
a = "1"
b = "2"
list.add(a)
list.add(b)
d = list[0]
    return render :text => list
    end
end
```

unfortunately for me, I get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

when I include the

```
lp = LexicalizedParser.new
```

am i doing EVERYTHING wrong? when I comment out the lp = ..., I get the list output, so jruby is working, and I can write java in my rails app and get the output.

can somebody point me in the right direction, maybe tell me what is wrong with this bit of code, but hopefully actually set me straight on how I'm supposed to be working with jruby and rails. Hopefully some input on Stanford Parser too (I know, it's a lot to ask). There seems to be very little by the way of documentation or example code that i've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. But I do think that you need to read up on how this parser works.

According to http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html, the default constructor works as follows:

> Construct a new LexicalizedParser object from a previously serialized
>   grammar read from a property
>   edu.stanford.nlp.SerializedLexicalizedParser, or a default file
>   location.

In other words, you are getting the NPE because the default constructor can't find enough information to create the parser.

If you grab the binary distribution from Stanford, appropriate grammars will be found in `grammar` directory. For example:

```
$ jruby -S irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'java'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'stanford-parser.jar'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> java_import Java::edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
=> Java::EduStanfordNlpParserLexparser::LexicalizedParser
irb(main):004:0> lp = LexicalizedParser.new("grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
Loading parser from serialized file grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [2.5 sec].
=> #<Java::EduStanfordNlpParserLexparser::LexicalizedParser:0x7d627b8b>
```

Comment: thanks banzaiman,  I had gone through the example docs, but I have to admit, without code examples, I always find it difficult to figure things out just by looking at the documentation. for instance, in the lexparser page you linked to, it includes multiple LexicalizedParser() options, none of which say .new, and the 3rd on the list specifies to point to the grammar. I've often struggled with this, which is why I prefer code examples to get a feel for the  language. But you got the answer (note, it was your code example which solved this for me). Thanks